# How to append the bytes of a bit-field to NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, bit-fields, nsmutabledata

I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
   int8_t foo        : 1;
} Bar;
```

I have tried to append the bytes to a NSMutableData object like so:

```
NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
Bar temp;
temp.foo = 1;
[data appendBytes:&temp.foo length:sizeof(int8_t)];
```

But I receive an error of Address of bit-field requested.  How can I append the bytes?

Comment: Have you tried `[data appendBytes:&temp length:sizeof(temp)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point to the byte, mask the needed bit, and append the variable as a byte:

```
typedef struct {
    int8_t foo: 1;
} Bar;

NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
Bar temp;
temp.foo = 1;

int8_t *p = (int8_t *)(&temp+0);    // Shift to the byte you need
int8_t pureByte = *p & 0x01;       // Mask the bit you need
[data appendBytes:&pureByte length:sizeof(int8_t)];
```

Comment: That's mighty undefined, there.

Comment: How could I do this if I had multiple bit-fields and needed to put more than one bit-field into that pureByte?

Comment: Use bit-wise operation, e.g. `int8_t pureByte = (*p & 0x01)|(*q & 0x04)>>1|(*r & 0x80)>>5;`